# jQuery mousemove with CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a game that involves clicking and dragging using jQuery. When you click inside the game div (red), a black block appears that you can drag around. I made a fiddle, here:

https://jsfiddle.net/r9pet266/6/

I wanted a slight delay between the mouse movement and the block movement, so I added a CSS transition property on the block.

The movement seems smooth as long as you click and drag inside the game div, but once you click outside the game div, clicking and dragging inside of it becomes very jumpy.

Does anybody know why?

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="game"></div>
  <div id="instructions">
    1. Click and drag inside the red box --> smooth <br>
    2. Click on the green <br>
    3. Click and drag inside the red box --> jumpy
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer {
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}

#instructions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 100px;
}

#game {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 270px;
  background: red;
}

.block {
  transition: 100ms;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: black;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var $block;

$('#game').mousedown(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $block = $('<div>');
  $block.addClass('block');
  updatePosition(e);
  $('#game').append($block);

  $('#game').mousemove(updatePosition);

  $(window).one('mouseup', function () {
    $block.remove();
    $('#game').off('mousemove');
  });
});

function updatePosition (e) {
  $block.css('top', e.pageY - 45 + 'px');
  $block.css('left', e.pageX - 45 + 'px');
}
```

Comment: Why the delay? Trying to understand so I can see if there is a good alternative way of doing it. It's definitely your transition though.

Comment: If you change your transition to 10ms it's much smoother

Comment: @AlainNisam The delay isn't necessary, I'm just curious why this happens. For me, even a transition of 1ms becomes very jumpy after clicking the green box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:

```
$('#outer').mousedown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

For whatever reason, canceling the default behavior on the green box stopped any jumpiness.

Updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/r9pet266/7/

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` has nothing to do with the solution. In your JS Fiddle `mousemove` event handler is bind to the `document` instead of `#game`, which solves the problem. Consider changing the accepted answer to mine.

Comment: The problem occurs regardless of where `mousemove` is bound. My solution works for the [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9pet266/9/) (binding `mousemove` to `#game`) and my game.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome, though sometimes fiddle is slow. Your solution enables you to drag the block box around the green, which is not the problem. The problem is when you click on the green once, then click and drag the black box inside the red, the box becomes jumpy. Comment-out the `mousedown` on `#outer` to see it.

Answer (score 1):

When you move the cursor outside the red and black box, it's outside `#game`, so the `mousemove` event handler is not firing. You should assign `mousemove` event handler to `document` instead of `#game`, like this:

```
$(document).mousemove(updatePosition);
```

See [updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9pet266/5/).

Answer (score 0):

```
// change
$('#game').mousemove(updatePosition);
// to 
$(window).mousemove(updatePosition);
```

The reason why the block stops moving is that your mouseover event listener is only being run when you are moving over the red box.

The jumping is thanks to [event bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing). The black box is a child element of the red box, so hovering over the black box means you are also hovering over the red box. (Check out the link for a proper explanation.)